# What is the difference between a tennis and a racquetball ball?

Tags: tennis, racquetball

What would happen if you played tennis with a racquetball or racquetball with a tennis ball? Tennis balls have felt and are heavier. If I practiced tennis with a racquetball for a week, and then switched to a regular tennis ball, what kind of difference would I feel?

Comment: I would not recommend trying this as it could contribute to developing tennis elbow. The racquets and balls used for both games are specific to each other and are not meant for the other.

Comment: PSA: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/how-do-i-answer-this-question/798)